# client side search engine

Tags: search-engine, client-side, glossary

I would like to get some suggestions on my current headache. I have been researching on search engine for client side browser. I am building custom glossary project. The idea of the search engine will be used for searching terms, keywords, or definitions.

Here are my requirements for this project

- no server side support. Total client side
- only for intranet
- build for browser that is not HTML5
- thousands of terms

Any suggestions or ideas on how to build the client-side only search engine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Barring a full desktop app, I don't see how you can do this without a server. Distribute the HTML files as a .ZIP file and browse them locally? If yes, you probably need to make a honking big page with the whole database inside it (as Javascript data structures) and search that way. Shouldn't be too hard with regexes etcetera, but I doubt whether you'll end up with a fun user experience...

Really curious why a simple server-side solution won't work :-)

Comment: the client want this on their website but they don't want their server side to be touched at all. ;(